# How to delete git author entries from intelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I just got a new work laptop and I'm still having trouble with the setup.
When I tried to commit some changes to a distant repository, instead of writing down my name and email in the git credential window, I wrote my username and password.
It failed for obvious reasons, but now the damn dropdown menu always show my password in clear and I want to delete that.

I did some research and got pointed toward the .git and .idea directories but even if I delete the whole project, this entry shows up again. It's obviously in some global log, but I have no idea where. Can someone point me toward the right place?